# Magento 1.9 : Switch Products msrp/price in onepage checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, onepage-checkout, msrp

I have created a custom module and created an observer method for "**sales_quote_collect_totals_before**" event. In this method, I check some of the quote data. Based on the current checkout data, I'd like to apply MSRP prices on products that are placed in the cart. Or switch products back to normal prices, if the criteria are not satisfied.

How can I do that?

Here's a sample of the code:

```
public function changeQuotePrices(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'onepage'){
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $quote = $event->getQuote();
        $quoteShippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        if (!is_null($quoteShippingAddress->getId())){
            $quoteShippingAddress->collectShippingRates()->save();
            $quoteShippingMethod = $quoteShippingAddress->getShippingMethod();
            if($quoteShippingMethod && $quoteShippingMethod == "payonpickup_payonpickup"){ 
                $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllItems();    
                foreach($cart as $item) {
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId()); 
                    $_msrpPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getMsrp(),true,true);
                    if($_msrpPrice > 0){
                        /* apply msrp product prices */
                    }
                }
            }else{ 
                /* apply normal product prices */
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: had you tried my answer below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
public function changeQuotePrices(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'onepage'){
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $quote = $event->getQuote();
        $quoteShippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        if (!is_null($quoteShippingAddress->getId())){
            $quoteShippingAddress->collectShippingRates()->save();
            $quoteShippingMethod = $quoteShippingAddress->getShippingMethod();
            if($quoteShippingMethod && $quoteShippingMethod == "payonpickup_payonpickup"){ 
                $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllItems();    
                foreach($cart as $item) {
                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId()); 
                    $_msrpPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getMsrp(),true,true);
                    if($_msrpPrice != ''){
                        /* apply msrp product prices */
                        $newPrice = $product->getMsrp(); //Your MSRP price 
                        $item->setCustomPrice($newPrice);
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newPrice);
                        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                        $item->save();
                    }
                }
            }else{ 
                /* apply normal product prices */

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `$quote->collectTotals()->save();` breaks page completely.

Comment: @zekia , can you remove that line and test again please?

Comment: I tried that. There's no error but the code is not working properly. The quote prices don't change.

Comment: I figured it out. `if($_msrpPrice > 0){` was the problem. Changed it to `if($_msrpPrice != ""){` and now it works

Comment: @zekia , its cool. If my answer help you then you can mark it as correct answer. :)

Comment: Sure, but there's another problem. I think that `$quoteShippingMethod` doesn't get the selected method. Because `if($quoteShippingMethod && $quoteShippingMethod = "payonpickup_payonpickup"){ ` is always true, even if I change the selected method. Any idea about that?

Comment: It's a syntax error. It should be `if($quoteShippingMethod && $quoteShippingMethod == "payonpickup_payonpickup")`. Please change that in our answer for future reference. Thank you

Comment: @zekia , Its updated :)